# data.frame to xts conversion result appear with quotation marks

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I know there are various examples on stackoverflow thats discusses this problem but even after going through them I was still unable to find a solution. What is the best way to convert to numeric with regard to OHLCV thats appearing as characters. What am I missing here or doing wrong?

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))
setwd("~/Documents/R")
library(jsonlite)
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)
library(xts)
library(quantmod)
library(anytime)
library(highfrequency)
library(lubridate)


setwd("~/Documents/R/STK/csv")

gdax <- read.csv(file="GDAX_BTCUSD.csv", sep="\t", dec=".", header=FALSE,    stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "NA")
options(scipen=999)
gdax <- na.omit(gdax[,c(9,4,5,6,7,8)])
colnames(gdax) <- c("Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume")

> class(gdax)
[1] "data.frame"

> head(gdax)
                 Date           Open           High            Low          Close    Volume
1 2016-05-16 00:00:00 461.4800000000 461.4900000000 461.4700000000 461.4900000000  5.345398
2 2016-05-16 00:01:00 461.4700000000 461.4900000000 461.4700000000 461.4900000000  4.650470
3 2016-05-16 00:02:00 461.4800000000 461.4900000000 461.4700000000 461.4900000000  1.360030
4 2016-05-16 00:03:00 461.4900000000 461.4900000000 461.4900000000 461.4900000000  0.586860
5 2016-05-16 00:04:00 461.4700000000 461.4700000000 461.4700000000 461.4700000000  0.135180
6 2016-05-16 00:05:00 461.4700000000 461.5000000000 461.4400000000 461.5000000000 11.257970

GDAX_BTC <- xts(gdax[, 2:6], order.by=as.POSIXct(gdax[,1], tz="UTC"))

> head(GDAX_BTC)
                    Open             High             Low              Close            Volume         
2016-05-16 00:00:00 "461.4800000000" "461.4900000000" "461.4700000000" "461.4900000000" "   5.34539836"
2016-05-16 00:01:00 "461.4700000000" "461.4900000000" "461.4700000000" "461.4900000000" "   4.65047000"
2016-05-16 00:02:00 "461.4800000000" "461.4900000000" "461.4700000000" "461.4900000000" "   1.36003000"
2016-05-16 00:03:00 "461.4900000000" "461.4900000000" "461.4900000000" "461.4900000000" "   0.58686000"
2016-05-16 00:04:00 "461.4700000000" "461.4700000000" "461.4700000000" "461.4700000000" "   0.13518000"
2016-05-16 00:05:00 "461.4700000000" "461.5000000000" "461.4400000000" "461.5000000000" "  11.25797000"

> class(GDAX_BTC)
[1] "xts" "zoo"

GDAX_BTC <- xts(gdax[,-1], order.by=as.POSIXct(gdax$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
# no changes in the output.
```

#

R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] lubridate_1.7.1     highfrequency_0.5.2 anytime_0.3.0       quantmod_0.4-12     TTR_0.23-2          xts_0.10-1
 [7] zoo_1.8-0           forecast_8.2        ggplot2_2.2.1       jsonlite_1.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.14       magrittr_1.5       munsell_0.4.3      colorspace_1.3-2   lattice_0.20-35    rlang_0.1.6        quadprog_1.5-5
 [8] stringr_1.2.0      plyr_1.8.4         tools_3.4.3        nnet_7.3-12        parallel_3.4.3     grid_3.4.3         RApiDatetime_0.0.3
[15] timeDate_3042.101  gtable_0.2.0       tseries_0.10-42    yaml_2.1.16        lazyeval_0.2.1     lmtest_0.9-35      tibble_1.4.1
[22] curl_3.1           fracdiff_1.4-2     stringi_1.1.6      compiler_3.4.3     pillar_1.0.1       scales_0.5.0

Comment: Looks like you have spaces in your `Volume` column. Remove them and you code works as expected.